# Finding the inverse of a MxM Matrix- Using gauss-jordan elimination

Tags: c, function, matrix, matrix-inverse

Now, I think i understand the concept. But when i put it all into code it doesnt work...

First i try to turn the matrix into a Upper Triangle matrix, but for some reason after column 2 it stops working..

The array im inputing is:

[1.00 ] [5.00]        [4.00]        [4.00]        [1.00]

[5.00]  [7.00]        [7.00]   [4.00]       [8.00]

[7.00]        [4.00]       [8.00]        [4.00]        [7.00]

[10.00]       [12.00]      [8.00]       [4.00]        [3.00]

[10.00]       [12.00]      [13.00]       [4.00]        [3.00]

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF4cg.png)

```
double** inverseMatrix(double **matA, int dimension)
{

    double** matInverse=malloc(dimension*sizeof(double*)); 
    double **holder = matA;

    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){

        matInverse[i] = malloc(dimension*sizeof(matInverse[0]));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < dimension; j++){
            matInverse[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
        matInverse[i][i] = 1.0;
    }




   for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){


        double pivot = holder[i][i];
        for(int j = 0; j < dimension; j++){
            
            holder[i][j] = (holder[i][j]/pivot);
            matInverse[i][j] = (matInverse[i][j]/pivot);
        }

            for(int row = i+1; row < dimension; row++){
                int number = holder[row][i];
                for(int col = 0; col < dimension; col++){
                    holder[row][col] = holder[row][col] - (holder[i][col] * number);
                    matInverse[row][col] = matInverse[row][col] - (matInverse[i][col] * number);
                }
                
            }
                
            
              
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. On what input are you trying to run it? What is the result?

Comment: Looks good, there must be some trivial typo or off-by one in the code. Use a small matrix (2*2, or 3*3) to test and add a few printfs inside your loops

Comment: @g_bor I made edits to the post with inputs and outputs

Comment: Hello there, it would be highly recommended to post the output instead of posting with images.

Answer (score 0):

While the function is incomplete and we can't tell if there are other problems at the caller site, an error is detectable in the posted snippet:

```c
int number = holder[row][i];
```

Here `number` should be a `double`.